# Short Description Limitation Error When Importing CSV File

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv

I Have created CSV file with all attributes particularly in 'short_description' field, I added value in table format as below

```
> <table cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""0"">   <col width=""215"">  
> <col width=""312"">   <tr>
>     <td colspan=""2"" width=""527"">SALES PACKAGE</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">In The    Box</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Main Unit, User Manual</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td colspan=""2"" width=""527"">GENERAL    FEATURES</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Brand</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Intel</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Type</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Processor</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Processor    Number</td>
>     <td width=""312"">i3-4130</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Supported    Sockets</td>
>     <td width=""312"">FCLGA1150</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Number    of Cores</td>
>     <td align=""right"" width=""312"">2</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Number    of Threads</td>
>     <td align=""right"" width=""312"">4</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Clock    Speed</td>
>     <td width=""312"">3.4 GHz</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Intel    Smart Cache</td>
>     <td width=""312"">3 MB</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">DMI2</td>
>     <td width=""312"">5 GT/s</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Instruction    Set</td>
>     <td width=""312"">64-bit</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Instruction    Set Extensions</td>
>     <td width=""312"">SSE 4.1/4.2, AVX 2.0</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Lithography</td>
>     <td width=""312"">22 nm</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Scalability</td>
>     <td width=""312"">1S Only</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Max TDP</td>
>     <td width=""312"">54 W</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td colspan=""2"" width=""527"">MEMORY    SPECIFICATIONS</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Max    Memory Size (dependent on memory type)</td>
>     <td width=""312"">32 GB</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Memory    Types</td>
>     <td width=""312"">DDR3-1333/1600</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">No. of    Memory Channels</td>
>     <td align=""right"" width=""312"">2</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Max    Memory Bandwidth</td>
>     <td width=""312"">25.6 GB/s</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">ECC    Memory Supported</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Yes</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td colspan=""2"" width=""527"">GRAPHICS    SPECIFICATIONS</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Processor    Graphics</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Intel HD Graphics 4400</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Graphics    Base Frequency</td>
>     <td width=""312"">350 MHz</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Graphics    Max Dynamic Frequency</td>
>     <td width=""312"">1.15 GHz</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">No. of    Displays Supported</td>
>     <td align=""right"" width=""312"">3</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Graphics    Video Max Memory</td>
>     <td width=""312"">1.7 GB</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Additional    Features</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Intel Quick Sync Video; Intel    InTru 3D Technology; Intel Wireless Display; Intel Clear Video HD
> Technology</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td colspan=""2"" width=""527"">EXPANSION    OPTIONS</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">PCI    Express Revision</td>
>     <td align=""right"" width=""312"">3</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">PCI    Express Configurations</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Up to 1x16, 2x8, 1x8/2x4</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Max No.    of PCI Express Lanes</td>
>     <td align=""right"" width=""312"">16</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td colspan=""2"" width=""527"">ADDITIONAL    FEATURES</td>   </tr>   <tr>
>     <td width=""215"">Features</td>
>     <td width=""312"">Max CPU Configuration: 1;    Package Size: 37.5mm x 37.5mm; Graphics and IMC Lithography: 22 nm; Advanced    Technologies: Hyper-Threading Virtualization Technology, VT-x with
> Extended    Page Tables, Intel 64, Idle States, Enhanced Intel
> SpeedStep Technology, Thermal    Monitoring Technologies; Intel Data
> Protection Technology - AES New    Instructions; Intel Platform
> Protection Technology - Execute Disable Bit</td>   </tr> </table>
```

Then i have imported csv file, it displayed following error

> Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined.

It supporting for particular limitation, if i added  more than 100 rows of value it shows error, how to solve this

Comment: Sku is a required field. Check file and 'define the sku'. Once that is done get back with us to see if there is other errors. If so please post. You can also check the. logs in the var folder if u have logs enabled to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Check your CSV, it seems to miss the `sku` column which is a required one.

To be sure you are providing a correct CSV try to create a product in the Admin Panel and then export a CSV from `System > Import/Export > Export`: the result is what Magento expects as input when importing through `System > Import/Export > Import` functionality.

Hope it helps.